# Battery operation after a short circuit - swift 7

Tags: laptop, battery

I have an Acer swift 7 SF714-52T laptop. There were short circuits on the motherboard, which I fixed at a service center.

However, after that the battery wouldn't charge - I was told to buy a new one. I replaced the battery, connected it. My computer shows that the battery is 100% charged but the battery light is blinking orange and when I remove the charging cable the laptop shuts down automatically.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Why not take it back to the service centre & ask them. They obviously didn't check their work.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot analyze a hardware problem over the internet.

Evidently, the "repairs" were ineffective and the damage to the motherboard
was much more serious than thought by the service center.
It's possible that the damage was too extensive and that the motherboard
needed perhaps to be entirely replaced.

You need to go back to the service center and demand to correctly repair
the computer. If the cost is too high, perhaps you should consider a new
computer.

If the cause of the short-circuit was a power-surge, you should also
consider a surge-suppressor or perhaps a UPS.

Comment: …or if it was liquid damage… insurance ;)